# Symfony2 Circular reference

Tags: symfony

Probably I have a problem with a loop in template.

```
services:
    twig_menu:
        class: Cms\PageBundle\Twig\Menu
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager', "@templating"]
```

Code php:

```
namespace Cms\PageBundle\Twig;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\Templating\EngineInterface;
class Menu {
    protected $em, $templating;
    public function __construct(EntityManager $em, EngineInterface $templating){
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->templating=$templating;
    }
    public function show($typ){
        $menu=$this->em->getRepository("CmsAdminBundle:Menu")->findBy(array('type_id'=>$typ));
        return $this->templating->render("menu.html.twig", array('links'=>$menu));
    }
}
```

Template:

```
<ul>
    {% for link in links %}
        <li><a href="{{ link.href }}">{{ link.name }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

When I cleared cache on the first refresh it is ok, next I get this error:

> Circular reference detected for service "templating", path:
>   "templating -> twig -> twig_menu".

Answer (score 3):

`templating` needs `twig`, `twig` needs `twig_menu` and `twig_menu` needs `templating`. Hence your circular reference problem. It might be because you're in dev mode, where Twig has a lot more dependencies, because of the profiler.

[Fabien Potencier himself has answered this problem on GitHub](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/2347#issuecomment-2838590) by saying "Just inject the service container and get Twig from that".  It's a quick and dirty solution, but it should work without any serious penalties.

But because injecting the service container is a code smell, you might want to avoid it. The deeper (more correct) solution is to refactor so that `twig` doesn't depend on `twig_menu`, but without knowing your entire project, it's hard to say how you could do that.

Comment: I don't know, how to fix it. I would like to create "global function", which in arguments have TYPE_ID and show it menu. `<nav> {{ menu.show(1) }} </nav>`. I don't want "local" in controller page, create the menu. It's stupid.

Comment: Sounds like you want to register a Twig fucntion, which would let you do something like `{{ show_menu(1) }}`. Alternatively, you can use a listener so your template has something like `<div id="menu"></div>` and then a listener received the entire rendered page and injects HTML into that div. This is roughly how the web debug toolbar adds itself - it uses `str_replace` to replace `</body>` with `<script>...</script></body>`.

Comment: Yes, function to Twig. Can I use: `<div class="menu" id="menu_1"></div>`, and "add/injects" code to menu?

Comment: @viko We're not discussing the original question now, so I'd suggest asking another question on SO about how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Inject the twig service, rather than the templating service. @twig is the service name.

Comment: A much cleaner solution, in my opinion, which worked in a Symfony 2.5.0 project.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of injecting the templating service within the `twig_menu` service's constructor you could provide it using a setter method. For example:

```
public function setTemplating(TwigEngine $templating)
{
    $this->templating = $templating;
}
```

Then in your controller use:

```
$this->get('twig_menu')->setTemplating($this->get('templating'));
```